# How to improve form provider performance in React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Since the react hook form provider is based on context Api, for large nested forms it can cause performance issues due to multiple re-renders during state updates. I came across this section in the documentation: https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#FormProviderPerformance, which basically uses react memo to stop additional re-renders unless the property isDirty changes.

I added the above implementation to my code and it has helped speed up the form performance a little but I now realize that my validations are not working since my memo does not check for updates to the formState.
https://codesandbox.io/s/provider-perf-forked-3jqlkj
In this example, we can trigger the required error message but can't remove it once user has typed something.

I also tried using the useFormState hook, but that means my entire form structure will re-render leading to slow performance. Is there any way out of this?

Comment: ```react-hook-form``` does not make that much rerenders if you use it the correct way. Don't use ```formState``` on top level, only where you need it. It is better to make correct state management than trying to improve the performance with ```React.memo```. It is true that it uses context Api, but that does not mean that it will cause rerenders if used correctly

Comment: It does when I try to access the formState from useFormContext(). From formState I need  to get the errors object in order to show validation messages. Since formState returns the entire form's states, it causes re-render. If I change an input in Component A, it automatically triggers re-render in ComponentB because ComponentB is consuming the formState from useFormContext().

Comment: formState is a Proxy. If you use anything from it it will cause rerender. But it rerenders only the components that use that property that changes. You might need to use useController for that, it will give you field state.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback. I am aware of the re-rendering complexity associated with formState. I am a bit confused how I can use useController to achieve my results.
Here is an updated codesandbox link depicting my problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/provider-perf-forked-44yh4x?file=/src/App.js
Here to avoid re-renders I added the react memo, but in doing so I am having trouble showing proper validation messages as user types or clears each input. 
It would be great to have some of your insights on this. Thanks